# Close a MessageDialog using the back key

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

Using Qt for Android I created a `MessageDialog` and opened it on a signal

```
onClicked: myDialog.open()
```

Unfortunately, pressing the back key doesn't close the dialog. `Dialog` doesn't inherit from `Item`, so I can't set its `focus` to `true`. `Keys` isn't available as well.

**EDIT:** example

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: appWindow

    width: 480
    height: 640
    visible: true

    StackView
    {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        // Implements back key navigation
        focus: true

        initialItem: FirstPage
        {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
        }

        Keys.onBackPressed: pop()
    }
}
```

FirstPage.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Item
{
    ColumnLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 20

        Button
        {
            text: qsTr("Doing nothing")
            onClicked: console.log("FIXME")
        }

        Button
        {
            text: qsTr("Open dialog")
            onClicked: mydialog.open()
        }

    }

    MyDialog { id: mydialog }
}
```

MyDialog.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

MessageDialog
{
    informativeText: qsTr("blablabla")
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Yes | StandardButton.No
}
```

Comment: I guess you can still use a `Dialog`, define the content to resemble the one from `MessageDialog`, thus use the `Keys` object to deal with the back key.

Comment: Sounds strange. Which Qt version are you using? Usually the problem is that it is dismiss even if you insert `Keys` handling inside. That's because the default behaviour - dismiss on back button - is coded inside `contentItem`. Could you post a minimum example code?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo added example code. Using Qt 5.5